# I need to stop an iMac update that is already downloaded and ready to install

Tags: macos, install

I am testing software on an El Capitan system. Unfortunately it had the download in the background option checked and now it has Sierra "ready to install".
The options are now, tonight or tomorrow.
I need to stop this update entirely.
I've searched my entire system for the installer file but cannot locate it. I searched for any file downloaded in the last day and sorted by size. There's nothing there that looks like a Sierra OS installer.
I turned off all the auto update options in System Preferences. I wonder if that will cancel the update from proceeding? I'll know tomorrow when I find out if it asks me again or not.
But if you know how to stop it immediately please explain how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer is usually in Applications. "Install macOS Sierra.app". Delete that, empty the trash (or direct-delete in Terminal).

> I am testing software on an El Capitan system

Get a virtual machine like Fusion or Parallels. Set up a new install of the OS and make a snapshot. Whatever happens next can be restored to the initial state in 30 seconds by restoring the snapshot.

VMs are also capable of running the next version. I run El Capitan right now and have VMs from 10.5 to Sierra. And with enough memory it's possible to have them all open at once.

Comment: The installer is not in Applications. I had already looked there. So it may be that it is actually not downloaded yet. Although the message seemed to suggest that it was. I'll know more as the day goes by and I observe if the OS asks to install it again or not. (the auto update options are now off).

Comment: I had been researching using VM on Macintosh recently. But I ran into a lot of mixed messages about Apple trying to block multiple versions of the OS even in virtual machines. There were also many sites discussing work-arounds and hacks that made me wary of proceeding in this direction. What vm product did you use and is it a smooth setup of additional Mac OS's?

Comment: The OS has stopped asking me if I want to update or install Sierra. That's great news.Now the option is turned off in System Preferences/App Store. What is unknown is whether or not there was actually an update already downloaded. I hope this experience will be of benefit to someone else in the future.